# Second hard drive seems to randomly freeze or unmount

Tags: mount, hard-drive, vmware

I tracing down a problem with a second hard drive and am now stumped.

My setup:  Dell Inspiron 17R-5721, 8GB Ram, running Ubuntu 13.10, Primary drive is Kingston 120GB SSD, secondary drive is a Seagate ST1000LM024 HN-M installed in the CDROM tray.

I run a VMWare workstation stored completely on the Seagate drive.  Everything was working fine until about 4 weeks ago.  Now VMWare comes up with a NVRam error and the vitual machine hangs because it can't write to the disk.  I get a corrupted vmdk file and the virtual machine is damaged beyond repair.

When the virtual machine is running and the error hits, the secondary drive seems unresponsive.  I try to use the host Ubuntu system to browse the files using Nautilus on the secondary drive and the drive doesn't respond for 4-5 seconds.  It seems like it was either unmounted and needs time to remount or something to where the Ubuntu OS is waiting on the drive.  For example, Nautilus has the "Loading..." status in the bottom right of the window.  I think the failure is in the connection of the drive and not VMWare nor the drive hardware.

I've checked the SMART status of the drive and all is okay.  No bad sectors or any other warnings.  I've even reformatted the drive.  I played with the mount options of the drive and have had the same problem.

Since the drive doesn't seem to be failing, I don't think replacing it is going to fix the problem.

*Edit:* 
As for the drive power management: Standby: never, APM level 255, AAM is off, and I've tried to enable and disable write caching.

**Any thoughts on where to look for other clues?**

Answer (score 0):

"Any thoughts on where to look for other clues?"

This is likely not the case for you but I once had an XP VM that randomly had an nvram error, and restoring it from a backup I had made just lead to a repeat occurrence. The problem turned out not be the host system but just a bad set of vm files. Cloning the virtual hard drive in a non-sector based manner and restoring it to the hard drive of a new blank vm solved the problem for me. Are you having this problem with a single vm or multiple, as that will tell you whether it's related to host storage problem.

Comment: I am using only the one VM.  Can you elaborate on cloning in a "non-sector based manner"?

Comment: It seems like the NVRAM error went away (at least for the last few days) since I upgraded to a newer version of VMWare.